# Product topology help required.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Can someone please help me with the following.

Let $G$ be a topological space with the collection of open sets being U = $\{u_i\;|\;i \in I\}$. Show that $G \times G$ is also a topological space. I want to show. Something like U'=$\{u_i \times u_i\;|\;i \in I\}$ is what make G$\times$G a topological space

Comment: What's the proposed topology that you are putting on $G \times G$?

Comment: Well can you construct a set like U in GxG so to make G x G a topological space

Comment: Let's put it this way: there are almost certainly _many_ different ways to put a topology on $G\times G$. I'm guessing that there is a specific one that you are intended to show actually _is_ a topology. Perhaps you could [edit] your question to include its description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to define a topology on $G \times G$. Many of them involve the topology of $G$ but you could also choose a different one. What I think you are asking however is proving that the product topology is actually a topology.

Firstly, there is a slight error in your statement above. A product topology defines the basis of the open sets as $U' = \{ u_i \times u_j \ \vert \ i,j \in I \}$ (note $i,j$ can be different or the same).

You need to show a couple things:

(1) $U'$ covers $G \times G$. This is obvious as $G$ is open and so $G \times G \in U'$.

(2) Let $B_1, B_2 \in U'$ and $I = B_1 \cap B_2$. Then for $x \in I$, $\exists \ B_3 \in U' \text{such that} x \in B_3 \subset I$. Hint, let $B_1 = U_1 \times V_1$ and $B_2 = U_2 \times V_2$ for $U_1, U_2, V_1, V_2 \in G$. Then construct a $B_3$ using intersections.

Comment: Your set $U'$ is only a base for the product topology, it is not the product topology itself. It is in general not even closed under finite unions. Just look at $G = \mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology and the union of the sets $(0, 1)^2$ and $(1, 2)^2$.

Comment: Thanks allot this is exactly what I wanted.